# Run as original user

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to run a process as the user logged on?
My setup requires an Administrator privileges, so during the setup every process that I run is run as the administrator user.
My problem is that my application needs to run as the user connected now.

I'm familiar with the "runasoriginaluser" parameter and the "ExecAsOriginalUser" function, but both of them don't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done that shows it isn't working. Can you post your script (or the appropriate section) and the Log file?

Answer (score 1):

runasoriginaluser does not work if you run the installer as the administrator:

[This is from http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNg0j.png)

I think you need to run the setup normally and enter in administrator information when prompted